# Event-triggered script unable to pass one particular <data> to script

Tags: powershell, dns, scheduled-tasks, windows-server, event-viewer

I am building a script for wINDOWS DNS servers that is to be triggered by Task Scheduler whenever an A record is created in DNS (Event ID 515 in Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit). I can pass NAME and Type from the event data to the script as arguments using -name '$(name)' -type '$(type)', but for some reason I cannot get RDATA from the event! I can see value for RDATA in event viewer, but when it is passed to the script, it's just an empty string.

Any wisdom on this would be appreciated! The following is the XML for the scheduled task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">

  <RegistrationInfo>

    <Date>2023-02-16T18:51:00.7831417</Date>

    <Author>SCG\scgtech</Author>

    <URI>\DNS Update</URI>

  </RegistrationInfo>

  <Principals>

    <Principal id="Author">

      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>

      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>

    </Principal>

  </Principals>

  <Settings>

    <AllowStartOnDemand>false</AllowStartOnDemand>

    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>

    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>

    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>

    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>Parallel</MultipleInstancesPolicy>

    <IdleSettings>

      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>

      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>

    </IdleSettings>

  </Settings>

  <Triggers>

    <EventTrigger>

      <Subscription>&lt;QueryList&gt;&lt;Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit"&gt;&lt;Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit"&gt;Event[EventData[Data[@Name='Type']='1']][System[(EventID=515)]]&lt;/Select&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryList&gt;</Subscription>

         <ValueQueries>

             <Value name="type">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='Type']</Value>

             <Value name="name">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='NAME']</Value>

             <Value name="rdata">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='RDATA']</Value>

         </ValueQueries>

    </EventTrigger>

  </Triggers>

  <Actions Context="Author">

    <Exec>

      <Command>powershell.exe</Command>

      <Arguments>-Command C:\scripts\PTR-Update.ps1 -type '$(type)' -name '$(name)' -rdata '$(rdata)'</Arguments>

    </Exec>

  </Actions>

</Task>
```

I would expect to be able to add the argument -rdata '$(rdata)', add $rdata to my parameter list in my script, and then be able to access RDATA from the event that triggered the task available to my script. This works to pass NAME and Type as arguments for the script, just can't figure out why RDATA won't work.

Comment: As an aside, which may or may not make a difference: To avoid an extra round of interpretation of the arguments passed to your script, use the `-File` CLI parameter, not `-Command`: `-File C:\scripts\PTR-Update.ps1 -type "$(type)" -name "$(name)" -rdata "$(rdata)"` - all of this assumes that (non-PowerShell) constructs such as `$(type)` are macro-expanded _before_ a call to PowerShell is made.

Comment: Thanks mklement0! I didn't give that part much thought. Same result unfortunately but the tip is appreciated.